# What are reasons of assertion failure

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 buttons that is created in .h file and one custom view

```
UIButton *btn_YourAccoun;
UIButton *btn_CreateAccoun;
UIView *view_top;
```

in .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    view_top=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320,60)];
    [view_top setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:80.0/255.0 green:79.0/255.0 blue:81.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    [self.view addSubview:view_top];

    UILabel *labelheader=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 5, 140, 20)];
    [labelheader setText:@"CREATE AN ACCOUNT"];
    [labelheader setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [labelheader setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
    [view_top addSubview: labelheader];


    btn_YourAccoun=[[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]init ];
    [btn_YourAccoun setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,65,44)];

    [btn_YourAccoun setTitle:@"YOUR ACCOUNT" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn_YourAccoun setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn_YourAccoun.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]];
    [btn_YourAccoun setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    CALayer *layer1=[btn_YourAccoun layer];
    layer1.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:232.0/255 green:230.0/255.0 blue:236.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    layer1.borderWidth=2.0;
    layer1.borderColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:184.0/255 green:185.0/255.0 blue:188.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;


    [view_top addSubview:btn_YourAccoun];

    btn_CreateAccoun=[[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270, 0, 55,44)];
    [btn_CreateAccoun setTitle:@"Create" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn_CreateAccoun setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn_CreateAccoun.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]];
    [btn_CreateAccoun setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    CALayer *layer2=[btn_CreateAccoun layer];
    layer2.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:232.0/255 green:230.0/255.0 blue:236.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    layer2.borderWidth=2.0;
    layer2.borderColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:184.0/255 green:185.0/255.0 blue:188.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    [view_top addSubview:btn_CreateAccoun];




}
```

it gives error when i was setting frame for btn_YourAccoun

> error-:Assertion failure in -[UIButton initWithFrame:],
>   /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UIButton.m:921

please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got this:

```
btn_CreateAccoun = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270, 0, 55,44)];
```

You shouldn't be using a factory method *and* an initialiser.  You either want:

```
btn_CreateAccoun = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270, 0, 55,44)];
```

or:

```
btn_CreateAccoun = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn_CreateAccoun.frame = CGRectMake(270, 0, 55,44);
```

UPDATE

You've asked in the comments what the reasons are for this type of error.  I assume that you mean assertion failures.  An [assertion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_%28computing%29) is something that a programmer puts in to make sure that things that shouldn't happen haven't happened.  That could be anything - if you come across an assertion failure, you need to know more about when and where it happened to know what's gone wrong.

In Objective-C, each object should be allocated once and initialised once.  Because an object should only be initialised once, the programmer has put in an assertion that it shouldn't be initialised more than that.  A factory method such as `buttonWithType:` allocates *and* initialises the object, so when you called `buttonWithType:` and then `initWithFrame:` you'd initialised it twice, and so the assertion failed.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: hey Simon thank you very much now it's working But tell me what are the reasons of this type of error

Comment: No problem. If you're happy with the answer, please click the green tick next to it. And welcome to stack overflow!